# com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil class not found error (again)

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play-services

I'm trying to integrate Google Cloud Messaging with my Android Project. So far I followed all advice I found and installed the Google Play Services, then checked it out as a project and added as a referenced project to my own project.

I found similar questions but none of the answers worked for me. I still get the class not found error.

When I import it in java code it finds it just fine, but when I try to run it on my device, this line throws the exception (nothing else so far references the google play lib project):

```
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

I am out of ideas, anything which might help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the exact desparate position and then I tried the last resort, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844393/how-to-completly-reinstall-adt).

I hope that it will work for you as well. Cheers!