# How to completly reinstall ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

After failing to make GCM work [(see one of many 'GooglePlayServicesUtil class not found' questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727465/com-google-android-gms-common-googleplayservicesutil-class-not-found-error-agai), desparately I tried to follow one advice which was to reinstall ADT. After doing so now nothing is working: SDK path was wrong (fixed), previous AVDs are broken, I can't create new AVD since the OK button is disabled, 'Check for updates' declares that there are no updaes but yet pops-up an error dialog saying: "Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno.
Unable to read repository at file:/C:/Program Files/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache/content-117422482.jar.
Premature end of file."

I assume that the best option for me now is to completely remove eclipse and ADT and start afresh.
What should I do to accomplish it? Previously I only removed the adt-bundle dir and apprently this was not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, at this point you are better off uninstalling ADT and resintalling it.

You have to remove the adt-bundle **and** delete the `C:\Users\mpascual\.android` folder. Then, install again.

pd: don't forget to replace "mpascual" with your username :P

Comment: Thanks!!! It indeed solved my endless mess in the way to make GCM work. Now everything works except creating new AVDs but I assume that googling around will find me the answer. Sorry that I can't up-vote, I don't have the required reputation yet.